# NameError: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS for SAVON gem

Tags: ruby, ssl, savon

I am using `RUBY 1.8.6` and `Rails 2.0.2`

I installed the `Savon` gem and when I try to run the following in my console:

```
client = Savon.client(:wsdl => "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL",
                      :pretty_print_xml => true,
                      :log_level => :debug, 
                      :log => true
                     )
```

I got the error message 'uninitalized constant'.

Then I tried `require 'savon'`

```
NameError: uninitialized constant OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext::METHODS
```

Comment: @bresc Thanks and `require 'openssl'`, `require 'thread'` `returns []`

Answer (score 0):

from Savon's website (www.savonrb.com)

```
Supported Ruby versions

MRI 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3 and 2.0
Ruby Enterprise Edition
JRuby (1.8 and 1.9 mode)
Rubinius (1.8 and 1.9 mode)
```

I guess you're on a unsupported version.
The following script works under MRI 1.9.3 on Windows and on Raspbian:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'savon'
require 'awesome_print'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?wsdl",
                      pretty_print_xml: true,
                      log_level: :debug,
                      log: true
  )

ap client.operations
```